# UIAlertController : How to show all separator lines when added much actions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uialertcontroller

When UIAlertController cannot show all action on screen, it can scroll.
But, separators disappears.
What should I do to display all separators?

iOS : 8.4
Xcode : 6.4

Example:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"test" message:@"test" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i] style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }]];
}

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{
}];
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's really not a good use of an alert controller.

Comment: Make a custom UIView instead and show it to the user with and animation. This will give you loads more options to custom it your own way.

Comment: this is not good design pattern. If you want to pick date then use `UIDatePicker` or any other picker as per your requirement.